# How to populate a struct that contains slice of structs with unknown size

Tags: go, struct, slice

I'm trying to get my head around the following simplified version of my problem.

I'd like to initialise a struct that has a slice of another type of struct within it.

I've looked at the various examples they seem to be for simpler versions where the struct just contains a slice of []int etc.

I can't seem to figure out what I whats needed to initialise my struct/slices.

The `Swells` slice can be an arbitrary length including empty.

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
)

type Swell struct {
        Slot      uint
        Height    float32
        Period    float32
        Dir       uint
}

type ForecastHour struct {
        Year      uint
        Month     uint
        Day       uint
        Hour      uint
        Swells    []Swell
}

func NewForecastHour() *ForecastHour {
       p := ForecastHour{}
       p.Year  = 2019
       p.Month = 10
       p.Day = 3
       p.Hour = 13


       p.Swells[0] := { Slot: 0, Height: 2.20, Period: 15.5,Dir: 300 }
       p.Swells[1] := { Slot: 1, Height: 1.20, Period: 5.5,Dir: 90 }
       p.Swells[2] := { Slot: 5, Height: 0.98, Period: 7.5,Dir: 180 }

       return &p
}

func main() {
        ThisHour := NewForecastHour()
        fmt.Println(ThisHour)
}
```

When I run the above I get:

```
./test.go:30:16: non-name p.Swells[0] on left side of :=
./test.go:30:23: syntax error: unexpected {, expecting expression
./test.go:31:8: syntax error: non-declaration statement outside function body
```

Comment: Please see the solution in => https://play.golang.org/p/ZYdkczjlC-R

Comment: Yes not a duplicate := wasn't the main issue.

Answer (score 2):

First, note that you can't assign a value to a struct property with `:=`. And to fix your main issue you just have to initialize `p.Swells`

```
func NewForecastHour() *ForecastHour {
       p := ForecastHour{}
       p.Year  = 2019
       p.Month = 10
       p.Day = 3
       p.Hour = 13
       p.Swells = make([]Swell, 3) // initialize with size 3

       p.Swells[0] = Swell{ Slot: 0, Height: 2.20, Period: 15.5,Dir: 300 }
       p.Swells[1] = Swell{ Slot: 1, Height: 1.20, Period: 5.5,Dir: 90 }
       p.Swells[2] = Swell{ Slot: 5, Height: 0.98, Period: 7.5,Dir: 180 }

       return &p
}
```

[Demo](https://play.golang.org/p/OpHkDUAqxYW)

If you have an arbitrary number of Swells to add, you can use the less efficient append method:

```
p.Swells = []Swell{}
p.Swells = append(p.Swells, Swell{ Slot: 0, Height: 2.20, Period: 15.5,Dir: 300 })
p.Swells = append(p.Swells, Swell{ Slot: 1, Height: 1.20, Period: 5.5,Dir: 90 })
p.Swells = append(p.Swells, Swell{ Slot: 5, Height: 0.98, Period: 7.5,Dir: 180 })
```

This works in a for loop.

Comment: OK many thanks, the initialize explains it !  The number of swells will always be arbitrary